# How to use AsyncTask, where do I have to put the code lines?

Tags: android

I have the following problem. After I got the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException I went looking for a solution, and as it seems, AsyncTask is the best way to handle this.

But after I read several pages I still don't know how to implement AsyncTask.

First I will tell you what i know so far together with my questions:

Here I would try to call the webservice.

```
package net.frontend.androidapp.statusrequest;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PurchaseRequisitionRequest extends Activity {


     private String METHOD_NAME = "parser" ; 
     private String NAMESPACE = "http://statusrequest.androidapp.webservice.backend.net";
     private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;  
     private static final String URL = "http://10.35.105.31:8080/SAPInterfaceWebservice/services/XMLTransfromer?wsdl";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.purchase_requisition_request_activity);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.purchase_requisition_request, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void checkStatus (View view) {



         try
         {
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
         EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.prRequest);
            String s= edit.getText().toString();
            long lineNr=Long.parseLong(s);
         request.addProperty("lineNr", lineNr); 

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
         androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
         Object result = envelope.getResponse();
         String hString = result.toString();
         String[] details = hString.split(",");

         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText("PR_Number: " +details[0].substring(1));
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).setText("Result1: " +details[1]);
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).setText("Result2: " +details[2]);
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).setText("Result3: " +details[3]);
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail5)).setText("Entered Number: " + lineNr);
         } catch (Exception E) {
         E.printStackTrace();
         ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText("ERROR: "    + E.getClass().getName() + " : " + E.getMessage()); 
         }  

    }
}
```

As far as I understand, the only thing I have to put here is

**new *MyClassName*().execute(a, b, c);**

right in my *CheckStatus* method. (This method is called, when a button is pressed)

So where does this line go?

**private class *MyClassName* extends AsyncTask**

I would now create a new class, give it a nice name and then put this line next

**protected Long doInBackground(Params... params)**

and then the code part of my *CheckStatus* .

Is this right so far?

The next thing is that I don't know, which parameters so you have to give the execute(a,b,c) call?

Can someone please give me some code example, using my code? I would really appreciate.
I am sorry for asking so basic questions, but I don't understand how it works.

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: read this documention http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: The [API reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are your first stop for these kinds of questions. In the event that the documentation is not satisfactory, find some tutorials or samples using your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public class PurchaseRequisitionRequest extends Activity {


        private String METHOD_NAME = "parser" ; 
        private String NAMESPACE = "http://statusrequest.androidapp.webservice.backend.net";
        private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;  
        private static final String URL = "http://10.35.105.31:8080/SAPInterfaceWebservice/services/XMLTransfromer?wsdl";

        String Error_Msg = "";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.purchase_requisition_request_activity);

            new asyncTask().execute();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.purchase_requisition_request, menu);
            return true;
        }

        private class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> 
        {
            ProgressDialog pd;

            protected void onPreExecute() 
            {
                pd.setTitle("Please Wait...");
                pd.setMessage("Saving...");
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.show();
            } 
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
            {
                if(result)
                {
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText("PR_Number: " +details[0].substring(1));
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail2)).setText("Result1: " +details[1]);
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail3)).setText("Result2: " +details[2]);
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail4)).setText("Result3: " +details[3]);
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail5)).setText("Entered Number: " + lineNr);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((TextView) findViewById (R.id.request_detail1)).setText(Error_Msg);
                }
                if(pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
            } 

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                try
                {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.prRequest);
                    String s= edit.getText().toString();
                    long lineNr=Long.parseLong(s);
                    request.addProperty("lineNr", lineNr); 

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
                    Object result = envelope.getResponse();
                    String hString = result.toString();
                    String[] details = hString.split(",");

                    Error_Msg = hString;

                } catch (Exception E) 
                {
                    E.printStackTrace();
                    Error_Msg = "ERROR: "    + E.getClass().getName() + " : " + E.getMessage();
                }   
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;               
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and then this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).

The so called "slow" code goen in the `doInBackground()` part of the newly created class.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I managed to miss the example, although I tried to find one. I had a look at the developer.android page page, but I didn't understand it. But now I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Google Volley (introduced in this year's I/O).
It has a simple interface for networking and remote image loading.

Check it out [here](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result, and 4 steps, called onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute.

AsyncTask's generic types :

```
Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
Result, the type of the result of the background computation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class and use this

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
       Context context;
       CallBack callBack;

       public RequestClient(CallBack callBack) {
               this.callBack = callBack;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();

       }

      @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          String responseString="";
          HttpClient client = null;
          try {
              client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
              HttpGet get = new HttpGet(LoginPage.url);
              client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 6000);
              client.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.timeout", 6000);
              HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
              HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
              if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                  responseString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                  Log.i("GET RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
               }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is "+e.toString());
            }
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return responseString.trim();
        }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               super.onPostExecute(result);
               callBack.run(result);

       }
}
```

And the main class

```
public  void postHttpRequest(final String userId,final String pass,final TextView error){
        url = "";
        Log.d("URL", url);
        RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(new CallBack() {

            @Override
            public void run(Object result) {
                try {
                    AppResponse =(String)result;


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Exception Occured", "Exception is "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        reqClient.execute(url);
    }
```

Create a interface Like this

```
public interface CallBack {
    void run(Object result);
}
```

Comment: hope this will help u